# I want add a piece of code where the game checks if the players velocity along the Y axis is under a certain number

Tags: unity, c#

The piece of code I want to write is where the game will check if the player is colliding with anything it will check this by looking at your y vector3 is under a certain number (its like this cause the gravity and collisions overall is a bit wonky) like if the players vector3 is under (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) then the game will call that line of code again if you're above that vector3 it will not call it again. My main problem trying solve this is telling unity who to check for which I'm not to sure how to do it. Whenever I do try to implement it all I get is errors sometimes I get really close but I'm unable to implement it due to some issues within the if statements.

As stated before I never was able to get implement I'll update things if I do figure it out on my own.

Comment: What specifically did you try and what specific errors did you get? This seems like it should be as simple as `if (myObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.y < threshold) { doThing(); }`, so it's not clear to me what help you need here.

Comment: If you want to check if the object is colliding with something, then why not use the [`OnCollisonStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay.html) method?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Player.velocity.y < 0.01f)
{
   // do thing
}
```